# PHP - browser crash, browser is unable to output as CSV

Tags: php, google-chrome, csv

I have a `csv.phtml` where i have all the row and column value

csv.phtml:

```
ID,column1,column2
1,french_words,dutch words
2,french_words,dutch words
10000,randrom words, random words
```

php:

```
$html = $this->view->render('print/csv.phtml');  
// this works, it prints $html       
//echo $html; 
//exit;     

// from here: it does not work 
$this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=report.csv')
        ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv')
        ->setBody($html)
        ->sendResponse();
exit;
```

[image]

How can i fix it? is there some strange characters in the $html which is causing the failure to the application/csv to render? how can i exactly find that invalid part?

Comment: well by the looks of it your server has crashed. On stack overflow you need to give more information and be more general with your questions as they need to help the community... not just yourself.

Comment: Try to reach that URL from `curl` and see what it responds with. `$ curl -i http://hide-it.com/report` Look at your server's error logs. This is not the "browser crashing", it's the browser telling you that your server doesn't respond.

Comment: What's in the logs? Check the apache|nginx logs. If you're using a framework (e.g. Symfony) check the framework logs as well.

Comment: How could that be a server issue, i have on same server all the other reports on same table, and they are all working fine except this one which is /report controller

Comment: Check also the response itself (chrome inspector tools or curl right away).

Comment: Please see my answer. why does not work on method1, and not working anymore on method2? is the network causing it or its a new BUG in PHP / Zendframework?

Comment: Is this a new Nightly, Firefox, Chromium, Opera, Google chrome BUG?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContent($html);

$headers = $response->getHeaders();
$headers->clearHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/csv')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=report.csv')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($html));


return $this->response;
```

Comment: This was not the CASE of the problem. Please see @deceze, he actually resolved the problem. It was a server php.ini settings.